# Split pandas dataframe into mutually exclusive subsets

Tags: python, pandas, random

I am am using regression tree analysis on a data contained in a pandas dataframe. In order to preform V-fold cross validation, I need to split my data into V random, mutually exclusive subsets

Here is what I've worked out so far where I add a new column V = 10 to the dataframe to denote which subset each sample is a member of:

```
def Vfold_Subsets(Data,V):
    subs = Data
    Data['V'] = V
    N = Data.shape[0]
    n = N//V
    for v in range(1,V):
        sample = subs.sample(n = n)
        Data['V'][Data.index.isin(sample.index)] = v
        subs.drop(sample.index)
    return Data
```

This method works, but I have a feeling there is a better way to do it?  A downside of this method is if N = 108, then

```
for v in range(1,V+1):
    print (v,': ',Data['V'][Data['V']==v].count())
```

returns:

```
1 :  10
2 :  10
3 :  10
4 :  10
5 :  10
6 :  10
7 :  10
8 :  10
9 :  10
10 :  18
```

And I think it would be better if I could achieve something like this

```
1 :  10
2 :  11
3 :  11
4 :  11
5 :  11
6 :  11
7 :  11
8 :  11
9 :  10
10 :  10
```

So that I don't lump all the remaining samples into the last bin.

Comment: Do groups need to be even-ish?

Comment: I don't know that they absolutely need to be, if I have a sufficiently large N I don't think it should matter?  But I would prefer them to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your function

```
def Vfold_Subsets(Data, V):
    return Data.assign(
        V=np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(Data))) % V)
```

Comment: Works great, Thanks!